# Different css in a div

Tags: jquery, css

Here's this row from a jquery css:

```
.ui-widget-header {
    border: 1px solid #e78f08; 
    background: #f6a828 url(images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_35_f6a828_500x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; 
    color: #ffffff; 
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I'd like to change the background to none, but just in the smalltabs div. This doesn't work however (I just tried to copy the line):

```
#smalltabs {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    .ui-widget-header {
        border: 1px solid #e78f08;
        background: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-weight: bold;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the HMTL code that goes with this CSS?

Comment: Anton's solution works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using important and correcting the selector

```
   #smalltabs {
       border: none;
       padding: 0;
   }
    #smalltabs .ui-widget-header {
     border: 1px solid #e78f08;
     background: none !important;
     color: #ffffff;
     font - weight: bold;
 }
```

Comment: I suggest only to use the `!important` rule to override inline styles. Most of the times you can solve it with specifying the right way without !important.

Answer (score 0):

```
#smalltabs {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
    #smalltabs {
border: none;
padding: 0;
.ui-widget-header { border: 1px solid #e78f08; background: transparant; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; }   
}
```

It also can be the case that it is being overruled. If so, try this

```
    #smalltabs {
border: none;
padding: 0;
.ui-widget-header { border: 1px solid #e78f08 !important; background: transparant !important; color: #ffffff !important; font-weight: bold !important; }   
}
```

EDIT: My bad i was thinking about background-color. Try this:

```
        #smalltabs {
border: none;
padding: 0;
.ui-widget-header { border: 1px solid #e78f08 !important; background: none !important; color: #ffffff !important; font-weight: bold !important; }   
}
```